# How to compress an asp.net project, so that i can transfer it over email?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I just want to know how to package up an asp.net project so that i can send it via email?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Zip/rar/etc. the folder?

Comment: and there are many other ways than email to exchange files nowadays. Why use email ? Email containing such files may simply be blocked by a anti-virus or so.

Comment: Zip it and throw it in https://www.dropbox.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the binary data from `/bin` and `/obj` folders. Make a copy and try to build it, if it works fine, use a compression tool like 7zip, gzip, rar etc. If not fix the errors and repeat.